# Не получается добавить переменную в alert

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

```
<?php       
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($select))  {
    ?>
      <tr id="<?php echo $row['id'] ?>">
        <td><?php echo $name=($row['name']) ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['desc'] ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['pages'] ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['price'] ?></td>
        <td><?php $start_date = new DateTime( $row['add']);
        $since_start = $start_date->diff(new DateTime(NOW));
        $minutes = $since_start->days * 24 * 60;
        $minutes += $since_start->h * 60;
        $minutes += $since_start->i;
        echo $minutes.' Минут назад' ?></td>
        <td><button class="delete">Delete</button></td>
      </tr>
    <?php } ?> 
    </table>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(".delete").click(function(){
        var id = $(this).parents("tr").attr("id");
        var name = $(this).parents("tr").attr("name");
        if(confirm('Вы уверены что хотите удалить?'))
        {
            $.ajax({
               url: '/delete.php',
               type: 'GET',
               data: {id: id, name: name},

               error: function() {

                  alert('Что-то пошло не так');
               },
               success: function(data) {

                    $("#"+id).remove();

                    alert("Удаление успешно"+(name)); // Как заставить выдавать name?
               }
            });
        }
    });
</script>
```

Не могу понять, что нужно сделать, все остальное отлично работает.

З.Ы. Если вдруг кому-то нужно удаление из mysql с помощью ajax, пользуйтесь, код рабочий!

Answer (score 1):

Вот так нужно было сделать:

`var name = $(this).parents("tr").children("td").eq(0).text();`

Теперь все корректно работает.

Answer (score 0):

```
alert("Удаление успешно" + id);
```

У Вашего `tr`-а нет атрибута `name`.

> но как чему нибудь присвоить атрибут name?

```
<tr id="<?php echo $row['id'] ?>" name="myname">
```

Но лучше:

```
<tr id="<?php echo $row['id'] ?>" data-name="myname">
```

и

```
var name = $(this).closest("tr").data("name");
```

Comment: Я извиняюсь за тупость, но как чему нибудь присвоить атрибут name? 
Я просто первый день этим занялся, и js вообще в первый раз вижу

Comment: Теперь он выдает просто "Удаление успешно name". А мне нужно, чтоб он брал нужное значение из таблицы при удалении